# Split URL path into components

Tags: python, url, parameters, split, components

Given an URL `http://www.example.com/users/john-doe/detail`, how can I create an list of this form `['/users', '/users/john-doe', '/users/john-doe/detail']`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to get the URL *path*, then split the parts and construct the path variations:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse  # Python 3.x
>>>
>>> url = "http://www.example.com/users/john-doe/detail"
>>> urlparse(url)
>>>
>>> path = urlparse(url).path[1:]
>>> parts = path.split('/')
>>> ['/' + '/'.join(parts[:index+1]) for index in range(len(parts))]
['/users', '/users/john-doe', '/users/john-doe/detail']
```